# Struts2 dojo submit button render issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, struts2, dojo

I have struts2 with dojo submit button(ajax call) in dialog window.I want to retain the popup window after submit the button.but its not retain the same form.

```
<div id="dialog-form">
<form action="finder" method="post" id="form1">
<textarea id="products" name="productNo"><s:property value='productNo'/>
        </textarea>
  <sx:submit targets="dialog-form"></sx:submit>
```

parent page form:

```
<div id="form_parent">
 <form action="search" method="post">
 -------------------------
 --------------------------
 </form>
 </div>
```

searchaction.java

```
public String finder()
{
 ---------------------
 return "search" //which is going to return parent page.
 }
```

when i'm submitting the page , its closing the popup window and opening parent page. How to retain the popup window ?

Comment: I am not familiar with dojo plugin, what is this "dialog-form1" in submit tag

Comment: Maybe `window.open` is what you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know struts2, but following the documentation at http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/dojo-submit.html, I would try something like :

```
<form id="form1" action="search">
    ---------
    ---------
    <sx:submit beforeNotifyTopics="/before" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.event.topic.subscribe("/before", function(event, widget){
        dojo.stopEvent(event);
        dojo.xhrPost({
            form : dojo.byId("form1")
        });
    });
</script>
```